# iMac late 2012, temperature issues

Tags: macos, temperature, kernel

I have a late 2012 iMac that's always worked really well but out of the blue it started to slow down significantly. It will work fine for half an hour and then slow to a crawl, cursor drags, starting/quitting apps takes forever, etc. I ran a dtrace profile and see a ton of these stack traces:

```
AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement`AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement::free()+0x55f1
mach_kernel`call_continuation+0x17
284
```

Which made me think it's something wrong with one of the thermal sensors. Rebooting doesn't fix the issue, I have to shut the box down for a few minutes. Resetting the nvram seemed to work for a bit but it came back.

I'm happy to open it up and change a part, but I've no idea where the sensor(s) are.
Any ideas, alternate theories or suggestions on how to debug this further?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you opened it to check for dust? 12 years is a long collection time...

Comment: After 9 years it just may have collected a lot of dust, would try to remove that first.

Comment: Yup, I cleaned it about a year and a half ago. I ran some experiments and what triggers this is the temp sensor on the PCHD reaching 80 C. The OS stays in this slow state even after the fan kicks in and lowers the temperature. Only powering down resets this.